# inconsistent result of cookies

Tags: php, cookies

If I push F5 button (refresh) for several times, the result sometimes different, like an inconsistent result, I just want a fix result. I kept looking the resolved of problem until now but I still failed and I don't know where are the mistakes.

the result is like this:

[image]

index.php image:
[image]

index.php:

```
<?php   
    include('c2gcon.php');
    include('logincheckmember.php');
    include('logincheckadmin.php');
    //include('urlmanage.php');

    //include('urlexplode.php');
    $urlget = $_GET['url'];
    $urlexplode = filter_var($urlget, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $url = explode("/", $urlexplode);

    $urlsave=$url[0];
    //print_r($url);
    echo "urlsave=$urlsave<br>";
    if($urlsave=='home'){
        include('uc.php');
        include('coorand1.php');
        include('home.php');
    }else{
        echo "<script language=javascript> alert('gila lu')</script>"; 
        echo "<br><br><br>gila lu keong<br>";
        include('uc.php');
        include('coorand2.php');
        include('home.php');
    }
?>
```

refference:
[coorand1.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnfum.jpg) and [coorand2.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCeHO.jpg)

Comment: Is there a loadbalancer active?

Comment: there's no a loadbalancer, it should be goes to the condition 1. I don't know why sometimes goes into the condition 2. But if it truly goes to the condition 2, then the alert and echo should be shown up, but it's not.